# return statement not returning values

Tags: c++

```
emp* emp::check(string a,emp* ceo)
{
   emp* l;
   employee* b;
   l=ceo;
   if(l->name==a)
   {
    cout<<l->name;
    return l;
   }
   b=l->j;
   while (b!=NULL)
   {
      check(a,b->junior);
      b=b->next;
   }
}

void main()
{
   l = check(d,ceo);
   cout<<l->name;
}
```

now initially the value of `l->name` is being printed but finally in `main` value of `l` is not being returned.
this means that it is reaching the `return` statement but `l` is not being returned.
can someone explain why?

Comment: Not all code paths in `emp::check` return a value. Compiler warnings are there for a reason.

Comment: @DCoder (and they are worth nothing if turned off. :P)

Comment: @H2CO3 Why would anybody turn those off? :)

Comment: You are discarding the return value of the recursive call. Are you sure you intend to actually return something useful?

Comment: @khajvah No sane programmer would explicitly turn off warnings, of course :) But almost every compiler I know has most of them turned off *by default.* And if one doesn't care reading the manual of his/her compiler (beginners usually don't give a frick about that), one will never find out that it's possible (and desired) to turn on warnings.

Comment: Is `l` a global variable or an external one? I don't see it declared in `main`.

Comment: `l` is declared on the 3rd line above. Even if it's declared elsewhere it's using the local variable.

Comment: `void main()` is wrong; C++ requires `main` to return `int`. Your compiler is doing you a disservice if it doesn't warn you about this, and your textbook is doing you a serious disservice if it told you to use `void main()`.

Comment: Usually a bad idea to use `l` as a variable name - often can be confused with the number `1` Ditto with `o` and `0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is happening is this, it is matching in one of the recursive calls to `check` and you then discard the return value. You need to change the function to look like this:

```
emp* emp::check(string a,emp* ceo)
{
   emp* l;
   employee* b;
   l=ceo;
   if(l->name==a)
   {
    cout<<l->name;
    return l;
   }
   b=l->j;
   while (b!=NULL)
   {
      l = check(a,b->junior); // <----- line changed
      if (l)
         return l;            // If we found something, return it. 
      b=b->next;
   }

   return 0; // <----- Always return a value
}
```

Also, there are various stylistic issues with your code, it would be clearer if you made changes something like this so that your variable and function names are useful:

```
emp* emp::findEmployeeByName(string name,emp* root)
{
   if(root->name==a)
   {
    cout<<root->name;
    return root;
   }

   // What on earth is ->j? Give your members meaningful names
   for (employee* worker=l->j; worker; worker = worker->next)
   {
      emp* match = findEmployeeByName(name,worker->junior); // <----- line changed
      if (match)
         return match;            // If we found something, return it. 
   }

   return 0; // <----- Always return a value
}
```

Comment: +1. This is good work. Do we need a variable called l since ceo is passed by value?

Comment: I generally prefer not to modify argument variables. I also prefer not to have variables called `l`.